# Jquery Fullcalendar hide some hours in Today view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, time, fullcalendar

I want hide or delete some hours in Today view, now working with minTime and maxTime option.

Te expected output is hour ranges
(7 to 12) 
(hide 13-14-16 hours rows) 
(16 to 22)

```
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: hdr,
                buttonText: {
                    prev: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
                    next: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
                },

                minTime: "7:00",
                maxTime: "23:00",

                editable: true,
                droppable: true
```

Any idea to learn please...

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old post, but it can still help someone

using the viewRender option you can search through the table and remove said hours depending on the range you use

```
viewRender: function(view, element) {
      $(element).find('div.fc-slats table tr[data-time]').filter(function() {
        var _t = jQuery(this).data('time');
        /* Searches for the times that we don't want */
        return ((_t >= '07:00' && _t <= '12:00') || (_t >= '16:00' && _t <= '22:00')) === false;
      }).each(function() {
        $(this).remove(); /* hide the unnecessary rows */
      });
  }
```